# Flask: Can one create a custom 302 (Redirect) page?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

During unit testing a Flask application I, at first accidentally, omitted the `follow_redirects=True` parameter, which caused the following test to fail:

```
from unittest import TestCase
class TestFlask(TestCase):
    def test_settings(self):
        # user not logged in
        r = self.app.get("/user/settings", follow_redirects=False)
        data = r.data.decode('utf-8')
        self.assertIn("Sign In", data)
```

For this page (/user/settings) the user needs to be logged in and would usually be redirected to the login page, which contains the words "Sign In". With `follow_redirects=False` I, of course, get an `AssertionError` (note the automatically generated HTML):

```
AssertionError: 'Sign In' not found in '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>Redirecting...</title>\n<h1>Redirecting...</h1>\n<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="/user/login?next=%2Fuser%2Fsettings">/user/login?next=%2Fuser%2Fsettings</a>.  If not click the link.'
```

## Question

How can I customize the HTML generated by a 302 redirect that is not being followed?

### What I tried

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
# ...
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
    return "page not found, {}".format(e)

@app.errorhandler(302)
def redirect(e):
    return "redirecting... {}".format(e)
```

Taking the same approach as I would for a custom 404 page causes a `KeyError: 302` upon starting the web server. I am aware that 302 does not indicate an error, thus, trying an `errorhandler` was destined to fail. I did, however, not find any alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3):

> The server's response payload usually contains a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the different URI(s).

But in practice the redirect payload is completely ignored by most user agents. When a browser encounters the `Location` header it immediately begins redirecting to the new page, so the payload of the 302 response is never rendered.

If you care about the behavior of non-browser user agents on unfollowed redirects (why?) you can just build a response like you would normally (e.g. using `flask.render_template`) and manually set `response.status = 302` and `response.headers['Location'] = '/path/to/redirect/to'`, instead of using the `flask.redirect` helper function. If you find yourself doing this sort of thing all the time, you could define your own `redirect` function to use instead, or you could write a Werkzeug middleware that transforms redirect responses for you.